# Is there any updated version of SPSource or alternative tool for SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is there any updated version of [SPSource: Reverse engineering tool for SharePoint](http://spsource.codeplex.com/) or alternative tool for SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010, preferrably with the [Community Kit for SharePoint Developer Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ee876627-962c-4c35-a4a6-a4d89bfb61dc). This allows you to browse in the Server Explorer down to your list, content type or fields, and you can right click and 'import' them into your Visual Studio project. This then shows you the CAML used to define those items.

Another alternative is SharePoint manager - it also exposes the XML used to define those elements - but I find the Visual Studio tools more useful, 'cos generally I want to do something with those lists/content types.

Even without the Community Kit, you can still import List definitions with just Visual Studio, I think.

Answer (score 0):

for sharepoint 2010 You can contact the author, Jeremy Thake, directly and ask if there are any updates. His blog: http://wss.made4the.net/default.aspx and Twitter: @jthake

You should also look into tools like ShaerPoint Manager 2010. Your other cool option is to create a list in the UI, then save the entire site as a WSP. You can then import the WSP in Visual Studio, and get the components you want from there

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/dc18ec30-f291-4d56-9aeb-c791ffb8d604